# How to configure a Cisco ASA with a static IP from Comcast

Tags: networking, dns, gateway, static-ip

I have a single static IP from Comcast. I have my modem/router set in a transparent bridge mode and I have a Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance (ASA) receiving the connections from the modem.

The ASA has a NAT rule for the statics (50.xxx.xxx.xx1) and that routes to a DMZ computer. However, when I hook up other devices to the ASA and check what's my IP I get my gateway IP (50.xxx.xxx.xx2)

Right now I have my DNS records all pointing to the .xx1 address and being managed via the ASA and DMZ computer.

My questions are these:

1) Can the gateway IP (.xx2) be used in DNS records to hit my ASA?
2) I've tried some basic configs with routing port 80 on (.xx2) to various internal machines from .xx2 after modifying the DNS records and creating a static PAT rule and have not had any luck.

3) Is this an issue with gateway IP usage or something else or am I just skipping a step somewhere?

Comment: Might be better answered on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up figuring out.

1) It turns out that there previously was a 1-to-1 NAT rule in the modem. I removed that from the modem and re-disabled everything.

2) After disabling the 1-to-1 NAT rule I found I was able to use Static PAT rules in the modem to forward traffic in to the DMZ from the Gateway IP address. I was unable to successfully test a second static NAT address but am somewhat concerned that the 5505 ASA I have might not allow that functionality or something weird is going on with that config. Regardless it turns out that the modem rule which was dealing with that IP - even though the rules were 'disabled' prevented the modem from running in a transparent mode in such a way that forwarding was not working.

So, not totally answered but the best I could figure out and I'm glad to move on from it :)